# Customizing WebMatrix.Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix

On my MVC application I'm using some security features (OAuth) from WebMatrix.
However, I needed some changes, so I've forked the project and added a few features to the **WebMatrix.WebData** assembly, using the code that is available on [CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/).

Now that I was trying to use those features on my application I've discovered that the **WebMatrix.Security** assembly's source code isn't available, so the new features I've added can't be used because they sit behind the **WebMatrix.Security** (added to my project via [this NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/WebMatrix.Security)).

Any ideas on how I can take advantage of the features built in WebMatrix.Security and also be able to customize it to some of my specific needs?
Or can I get the WebMatrix.Security source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a *partial* answer, I can say that the source code for **WebMatrix.Security** is in fact available, but the assembly was renamed to **Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth**, as pointed by [Marcin Dobosz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358970/marcind) in this [discussion](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/359176).